# In Excel, if cell is blank OR formula result is 0, then how to show blank cell instead of #VALUE! error?

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a table which plans for the future. So, cells containing a future calculation are going to be blank. They also might be 0. In either case, I want to show a blank. Instead, I get `#VALUE!` error. I don't want to see that error.

Here is what I tried, but it still shows the `#VALUE!` error:

```
=IF(OR(SUM(L7*D18)=0,SUM(L7*D18)=NA()),"",SUM(L7*D18))
```

I assumed that `NA()` means the cell is blank.

I also tried these which all still show the `#VALUE!` error:

```
=IF(OR(SUM(L7*D18)=0,SUM(L7*D18)=""),"",SUM(L7*D18))

=IF(OR(SUM(L7*D18)=0,"",SUM(L7*D18)="",""),"",SUM(L7*D18))

=IF(OR(SUM(L7*D18)=0,"",SUM(L7*D18)=NA(),""),"",SUM(L7*D18))
```

None of these work and it still shows the `#VALUE!` error:

How can I get this working so that `#VALUE!` is not returned and instead it is blank, if a referenced cell is blank or the result is 0?

Comment: No, `=NA()` is the worksheet's `#N/A` error.

Comment: Your `#VALUE!` is because L7 and/or D18 is not a number.

Comment: No it is because it happens to be a blank cell (formula only without any output). It is referencing another cell which checks it there is anything and then outputs `""` if the answer is 0 showing a blank, unfortunately excel doesn't understand that and gives an error. It is unavoidable, best solution is to simply hide the error as in the solution below which works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be what you want:

```
=IF(L7*D18=0,"",L7*D18)
```

Note that all of your `SUM` functions are superfluous

IF you want to suppress that `#VALUE!` error, you can do something like:

```
=IFERROR(IF(L7*D18=0,"",L7*D18),"")
```

Comment: You missed the point with your first formula. Your first formula which gives the `#VALUE!` error was my original formula before writing this question. So, my question was about how to use the OR function effectively to have two factors - blank cell referenced or end result 0. Your second formula works though. `IFERROR` was the answer I needed to suppress the error. Since the result is as desired, I am accepting the answer.

Comment: @hblrvce The reason I gave both formulas is that I was uncertain as to whether you wanted to fix your data so as to avoid the `#VALUE!` error, or merely suppress it if it appeared.

Comment: My intent was merely to hide the `#VALUE!`from the otherwise working formula, as this only appeared at times (like future months) where there was a blank cell referenced, but, e.g. knowing that the future month is in the future and won't have data yet, didn't want to see the error as [the supposed error] was already known, implicit, and unimportant.

Comment: @hblrvce Neither blanks (empty cells) nor zero's should cause the error.  Blanks get coerced to a zero by the multiplication operator.  What is really in the "blank" cells?

Comment: The error is caused if a blank cell *(not totally blank, but it is a formula which shows a blank rather than a 0 in certain cases)* is *referenced* inside the formula. Sorry but it does not get counted as a 0.

Comment: @hblrvce That is odd. I cannot reproduce that with an empty cell, although, of course, I can if the cell contains a null string, and only appears blank.

Comment: Please see my updated comment, the case in point is the *referenced* cell is not totally blank. It contains a formula which, in some cases, results in a 0 which it then outputs an empty cell. Like you updated in your comment above, it is a null string, not a total blank, it only appears blank and that is why it generates an error when the formula is trying to reference it.

Comment: @hblrvce Your updated comment clarifies. A more specific solution could be crafted, but is probably not necessary, especially if you can guarantee that the contents of those cells will always be either a null string, or a number.